# How do I best reuse html code for menus

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, nav, code-reuse

I'm making a larger website using HTML, css, JSP and Java-servlet.

I've made a menu using `< nav>` `< ul>` `< li>` (***navigation***). When i hover, sub-menus drop-down. It looks like this:

[image]

I want to reuse this menu on all my pages. It will change a lot so I need Single Source of Truth - No duplication of code. I've been looking in to php/js but haven't been able to get it to work.

**I imaging that it will work like this**:

- File only containing the HTML-code (like my menu) that are reused on all pages.
- File that make the magic work.
- Few lines of code that gets added to each page, at the place the menu should be. (maybe a line to tell what script it runs)

**Notes:**

- I'd like this to work for most (if not all) web-browsers.
- The drop-down menu should go over text below.

Comment: Load in menu.html with Javascript, append it to the parent div on each page.

Comment: Why did you tag PHP if you're using JSP/Java?

Comment: jsp include feature can be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the include feature given by jsp:

```
<%@ include file="menu.html" %>
```

Comment: This post made me find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837714/jsp-include-page-doesnt-work
Now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the Tiles framework .  [Look here](https://tiles.apache.org/) for more info